# Can I obtain the audio of president Eisenhowers message coming to me from a satellite circling in outer space?

Tags: artificial-satellite, history, united-states, audio

I remember hearing a recording of this speech some time ago. However searching for it again has been difficult, which led me to believe that I probably heard a recreation from someone else. In this qz.com [article](https://qz.com/870600/the-first-voice-transmission-from-space-was-eisenhower-wishing-peace-on-earth-from-a-nuclear-missile/) on the event I found a transcript of the speech, and [here](https://soundcloud.com/smithsonianmag/score-audio) an audio file. I would like to know if they are genuine, and if not, if I can find a genuine version of it.

> This is the President of the United States speaking. Through the marvels of scientific advances my voice is coming to you from a satellite circling in outer space. My message is a simple one. Through this unique means I convey to you and to all mankind America’s wish for peace on earth and good will toward men everywhere.

[image]

(click to view)

Comment: That audio file was published by the Smithsonian, unlikely it's a recreation.

Comment: This is a great question! Since links can break over time I've included a few extra bits.

Comment: This is getting more and more interesting! I've read the Quartz article about how the recording was transmitted *into the tape recorder* while it was in the nose cone of the rocket just before launch. Now I'd like to know if that Smithsonian Soundcloud is a direct recording, or if it is a recording of the *received broadcast* by the satellite once in space.

Comment: Hi, do you think that the recording in my answer is the one you are looking for? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

#### My answer is wrong!

I just realized that this transmission of Eisenhower was reflected off of a balloon in 1960, but the question is really asking about the transmission in 1958 from [SCORE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCORE_(satellite))    `1958-006A`. See [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/58047/12102).

#### Here is the wrong answer, left for its potentially interesting content:

Sure you can! Eisenhower's recorded transmission appears within the first minute of the YouTube video below. This seems to be part of the "Recently rediscovered audio recordings from the JPL archives..."

From https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=6660

> Recently rediscovered audio recordings from the JPL archives, for instance, highlight the lab's involvement in America's early attempts at satellite communications.
>
> One of these vintage recordings comes from NASA's first communications satellite, [Project Echo](http://history.nasa.gov/SP-4308/ch6.htm), which bounced radio signals off a 10-story-high, aluminum-coated balloon orbiting Earth in 1960. This form of "passive" satellite communication -- which they dubbed a "satelloon" -- was an idea conceived by an engineer from NASA's Langley Research Center, Hampton, Virginia, and a project managed by NASA's Goddard Space Flight Center in Greenbelt, Maryland. JPL's role involved sending and receiving signals through two of its 85-foot-diameter antennas at the West Coast Goldstone tracking station in the Mojave Desert.
>
> The Echo transmissions include a greeting from President Dwight D. Eisenhower, explaining how Echo fit into the U.S. program of peaceful space research accessible to other countries, and a message from then-Senator Lyndon B. Johnson imagining a "not too distant future when one man, one program, can be seen and heard simultaneously in every living room of the world.

**This video is one of several in a group of interesting vintage space items in the NASA Jet Propulsion Laboratory YouTube channel:**